# Calculate Workday from Work Hours Spread Across 2 Calendar Days - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please refer to the data image below:

[image: Table Structure]

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblData](
    [agentName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [loggedMins] [float] NULL,
    [activeMinutes] [float] NULL,
    [holdMinutes] [float] NULL,
    [inactiveMinutes] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample Data:

```
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/21/2018 23:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 00:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 00:30:00', 30, 0.018, 0, 29.982) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 01:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 29.982) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 01:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 29.016) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 02:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 0) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 02:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 18.132) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 03:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 03:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 04:00:00', 27.55, 0, 0, 27.55) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 18:00:00', 19.1166666666667, 1.86578666666667, 0, 16.9660416666667) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 18:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 19:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 19:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 26.532) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 20:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 14.568) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 20:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 21:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 21:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 11.232) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 22:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 13.266) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 22:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 23:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/22/2018 23:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 16.551) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/23/2018 00:00:00', 30, 4.416, 0, 25.584) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/23/2018 00:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/23/2018 01:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/23/2018 01:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/23/2018 18:00:00', 30, 0, 0, 30) 
Insert Into TblData Values ('Doe, John', '01/23/2018 18:30:00', 30, 0, 0, 30)
```

My problem is that I need to calculate work date on the basis of 'DateTime' column. John Doe works from 6PM to 4 AM. Work date needs to be added to new column which should be equal to 6PM date. Below is my logic:

1. Compare DateTime of current column with previous column along with agentName.
2. If difference is half hour and colleague is same, update final column with as of date of previous row.

I am having a hard time in translating into a code :( HELP!

Comment: An image isn't worth much in the SQL world I'm afraid. We can't interact with your data when it's like that. Please post your table's DDL, along with your sample data in a **consumable** format: [Forum Etiquette: how to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: I believe I'd recommend a ShiftId column be added to your database.  Otherwise, you'll be doing these complex calculations all sorts of places.  And it'll be very slow...you need a stored way to tie this data together

Comment: @Larnu: updated the question. Thank you so much for suggestion.

Comment: Sadly, adding a column isn't really in my hands. I am a mere consumer of this data with no authorization of updating the structure.

Comment: Great effort. :) Much better. +1

Comment: What's your expected output? And which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Sadly, your issue may not be solvable. Your logic is based on rows in a particular order - but you have no column or set of columns that can be used to define this order. You reference "... and colleague is same" - but your sample data does not demonstrate this. In addition, your logic is based on knowledge that is hard-coded in your description. John Doe works from 6pm to 4am - where is this defined? And what about other persons? Lastly, it appears that most of the columns you have provided are irrelevant to the discussion - simplify things and remove them.

Comment: By using row number over over agentName and [Datetime] field, I can create an ordered list. The key here is to group and code consecutive timestamps (the ones that are separated by 30 minutes) together in one cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second answer:

```
SELECT  *
,       (SELECT MIN(DateTime)
         FROM   tblData S
         WHERE  S.DateTime <= M.DateTime
                AND S.DateTime > DATEADD(HOUR, -12, M.DateTime)
        ) ShiftStart
FROM    tblData M
```

Probably your best alternative then - this works on the idea that a shift will be no more that 12 hours, but you can tweak that.  Also not the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Matther Baker works perfectly!! I simple ranked rows by agentName and time; and then added agentName to the code so that the time for every agent gets counted separately:

```
--CREATING A TEMP TABLE
Select 
    row_number() over(order by agentName, [DateTime] asc) as [Rnk], * 
Into ##TmpData
from TblData
Order by agentName, [DateTime] asc

--ACTUAL LOGIC

SELECT  *,
       (SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM   tblData S
        WHERE  S.DateTime <= M.DateTime
        AND S.DateTime > DATEADD(HOUR, -15, M.DateTime) and S.agentName = M.agentName
       ) ShiftStart
FROM    ##TmpData M


--DROPPING TEMP TABLE
Drop Table ##TmpData
```

I saw that no one ever did a shift for more than 13 hours and hence added buffer and changed time interval to 15.

Thank you so much guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.  I've cast the datetime to time only and put a pivot point of midday, if time is after midday then its today. if its before midday then its yesterday.  I choose midday in case of early starts/late finishes etc.

```
SELECT  *
,       CASE WHEN CAST(DateTime AS TIME) > '12:00:00' THEN CAST(DateTime AS DATE)
             ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(DateTime AS DATE))
        END AS WorkDate
FROM    @tblData
```

That will give you a column you can group by.  Maybe wrap it in a cte to help.

Comment: PS. Nice listing of data to make it easy for us to read.  Cut and paste code is the way to go.

Comment: This works perfectly in case of our dear John Doe here. But won't work when someone does a shift that begins in morning and ends in evening. Let's say someone starts at 10 AM and ends at 8 PM. The shift date shouldn't really change then.

Comment: In That case you'll need to store a pivot point to allow you to define start and end time.  If you aren't allowed to change the tables and data then I'd consider creating a separate table and cross referencing to that. Something to hold shift patterns etc.  Your other option is to run cumulative totals that reset after a given time. But thats very resource heavy, and I'd avoid if possible.

Comment: People don't do a fixed shift here and hence there can't be a reference point. :( I'll be adding these points to my question.